# A silly error with looping over the Array

Tags: javascript

I just read a article about `for in` statement: [blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)
 and created a little array:

```
<script>
var stuff, index;
stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
stuff.name = "Foo";
for (index in stuff) {
x = document.getElementById("demo")
        x.innerHTML = console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index])
}

</script>
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone show me what is wrong with it?

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/900cfufk/). What it does is a bit odd, though: It outputs to the console and repeatedly sets an element's HTML to `"undefined"` (since `console.log` doesn't return anything). But as I tried to say in that blog post, don't use `for-in` for this unless you really have a good reason to. Related question here on SO: [*For-each over an array in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Sorry but `x.innerHTML = console.log()` makes my eyes hurt, really.

Comment: :) Agree with @ÁlvaroGonzález, what's up with that console.log there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the result to the former result and change the call of `console.log` and add for the display a break.

```js
var stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    index,
    x = document.getElementById("demo");

stuff.name = "Foo";
for (index in stuff) {
    x.innerHTML += "stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index] + '<br>';
    //          ^^                                          ^^^^^^^^
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` will log in the console

and `innerHTML` will set html content.

These are two different operations.

And if you want to set the html content to the strings, then I would suggest you form a single string and then set `innerHTML` , this will reduce dom operations/manipulation.

```js
var stuff, index;
stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
stuff.name = "Foo";
var str = "";

for (index in stuff) {
  console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index])
  str += "stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index] + "<br/>";
}
x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Can we remove this:   console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index])
?

Comment: Yes  you can remove it, if you don't want to log anything in the console.

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot define innerHTML to be console.log funciton.
The function does not return the string you put in it. So it will be undefined.
Secondly you override the innerHTML every loop. If you want to stack you need to concatenate strings.
And you dont need to call document.getElementById every loop if is the same.

```
<script>
var stuff, index;
stuff = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
stuff.name = "Foo";
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
for (index in stuff) {
    var string = "stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index];
    console.log(string );
    x.innerHTML +=string ;    
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that you run your code before the DOM has loaded (and more specifically the element with `id="demo"`) so if you open the JavaScript console (<kbd>F12</kbd> in many browsers) you'll see a complaint about `x.innerHTML` like:

> TypeError: x is null

Even if I'm wrong, this code suggests that you aren't really aware of the console and expect to see output on the page itself, something that won't happen:

```
x.innerHTML = console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = " + stuff[index]);
```

This is all you should be doing:

```
console.log("stuff[" + index + "] = ", stuff[index]);
```

(Please note the additional comma to avoid type casting to string.)